# Route resolver is executing before the AppComponent's constructor finishes

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing

I am using resolver to pre fetch data before moving to the route say "employee/add". This works fine if I navigate using router link. But when I do refresh on route "employee/add" then resolver service executed before the AppComponent constructor finished.

In my resolver service I am using some data which I am fetching from session service and this session service make API request from the AppComponent's constructor.

My AppComponent code as follows.

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private sessionService: SessionService,
    private featureService: FeaturesService
  ) {
    this.authService
      .checkSession()
      .pipe(
        concat(
          this.sessionService.loadUser(), // fetch user info from the server -> need this info for other services
          this.featureService.getFeatures() // fetch features list
        )
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
      });
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: add your `authService` `ngOninit` instead of constructor

Comment: That's ok , but this will not solve my issue.